# Loop infinito ao ler inteiros com Scanner

Tags: java, scanner

Estou tentando tratar uma exceção dentro de uma estrutura de repetição `for`, porém estou tendo dificuldades, pois o `catch` não está retornando para o `for`, e ao digitar um valor inválido, ele fica num loop infinito mostrando a **mensagem de erro**.

Segue o código abaixo:

```
public class Courses {

    private static Set<Integer> listOfStudents = new HashSet<>();

    public static void calculate(Integer students, Scanner sc) {
        for (int c = 0; c < students; c++) {
            try {
                listOfStudents.add(sc.nextInt());
            } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
                System.out.println("Invalid code! Try again");
                c--;
            }
        }
    }

    public static int getNumberOfStudents() {
        return listOfStudents.size();
    }

}
```

O 'c--' serve para não perder a quantidade do código dos estudantes a ser digitada, por exemplo:

- Se eu digitar 3 estudantes, e passar um valor inválido, ele irá decrementar 1 no `for` e pedir para digitar um valor válido.

Comment: *ele fica num loop infinito *, sim vai ficar, olha o seu código, se der erro vc decrementa a variável "c", e o que faz no `for`? incrementa de novo. Para tratar isso, do valor inválido, seria melhor colocar esse bloco dentro de um `while`, como uma condição de ficar executando até que o valor seja válido

Comment: Sim, eu entendi, mas isso é justamente o que eu quero fazer, digamos que o 'c' esteja valendo 0, ao der um erro, ele irá para -1, e será incrementado para 0 de novo (sendo assim, eu não perco a "vez" de cadastrar um estudante), assim deveria entrar novamento no bloco 'try', mas ele fica em um loop no catch. Desculpa se eu não entendi direito, mas poderia me mostrar um exemplo se esse for o caso?

Comment: só que loops for não foram feitos para se alterar o valor da variável dessa maneira, ele é um contador contínuo e não se deve mexer nele, para o que vc quer fazer existem outros meios, como por exemplo o que eu falei, usar um laço `while` que só vai sair se o valor for válido, sem alterar o valor do contador do `for`, tente fazer dessa forma

Comment: Eu fiz com 'while' , e continua dando o mesmo problema. Deixe o 'while' dentro do 'for', e dentro tem o bloco 'try/catch', e mesmo assim fica dando aquele loop. Será que tem algo em específico do 'catch' que eu não sei?? Sou meio novato nessa área ainda

Comment: @RicardoPontual a variável `int c` é uma simples variável como qualquer outra, sendo apenas visível no _scope_ do `for`, podendo ser usada tal como as outras variáveis. Desta forma, não deverá receber um "tratamento especial".

Comment: só estou dizendo que o propósito do `for` é ser um contador linear, vai de 1 a 10, etc... se precisa ficar alterando um contador, o `for` não é a melhor opção, mas alterar o valor da variável pode, mas não é a melhor forma de controlar o loop :)

Comment: Aaaah entendi, então eu posso alterar o valor da variável do 'for', mas não é aconselhável, é isso neh?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O "loop infinito" acontece uma vez que o método `Scanner::nextInt` não consume o *input* que gerou o erro, logo o *buffer* ficará com o que foi escrito até que seja consumido. Assim, dentro do `catch` deverá ser consumido o *input* errado através da chamada ao método `Scanner::nextLine`.

```java
public static void calculate(int students, Scanner sc) {
    for (int c = 0; c < students; ) {
        try {
            listOfStudents.add(sc.nextInt());
            ++c;
        } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
            sc.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Invalid code! Try again");
        }
    }
}
```

Nota: Por simplificação poderá colocar o `c++` apenas depois da leitura se ter realizado com sucesso, retirando assim o `c--`.

Comment: Entendi, mas não sabia que dava para fazer esse tipo de implementação no for, isto é, colocar o c++ depois de uma certa condição e etc, existe algum nome específico para esse macete?

Answer (score 0):

Primeiro vamos entender este código de exemplo:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
try {
    System.out.println("digite um número: ");
    System.out.println(sc.nextInt());
} catch (InputMismatchException e) {
    System.out.println("deu erro, tente novamente: ");
    System.out.println(sc.nextInt());
}
```

Suponha que no primeiro `nextInt()` eu não digite um número. A saída será:

```
digite um número: 
abc
deu erro, tente novamente: Exception in thread "main" 
java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:864)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2117)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076)
    ...
```

O que acontece é que, como eu não digitei um número, o primeiro `nextInt()` lança a exceção e o *scanner* não avança na string (ele continua parado antes do `abc`). Em seguida, quando eu chamo `nextInt()` novamente, ele tenta ler novamente o `abc`, e dá erro novamente (`InputMismatchException`).

É isso que está acontecendo no seu loop. Quando o `nextInt()` recebe um valor inválido, cai dentro do `catch` (e o *scanner* não avança na string). Em seguida, ele vai para a próxima iteração do `for` e o `nextInt()` tenta ler o valor inválido que havia sido digitado anteriormente (e cai dentro do `catch` de novo, e volta para o `nextInt`, que cai no `catch`...). E como dentro do `catch` você decrementa a variável de controle do *loop*, ele nunca sai do `for`.

O que você pode fazer é [chamar `nextLine()` enquanto o valor digitado não for um número](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2696098) (o que pode ser verificado com `hasNextInt()`), assim o *scanner* pula o trecho inválido:

```
for (int c = 0; c < students; c++) {
    try {
        while(! sc.hasNextInt()) {
            // consome a entrada até que seja encontrado um número
            sc.nextLine();
        }
        listOfStudents.add(sc.nextInt());
    } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
        System.out.println("Invalid code! Try again");
    }
}
```

Assim eu garanto que o `nextInt()` só será chamado quando o próximo valor a ser lido é um número. Note também que agora você não precisa ficar decrementando o `c`, pois ele só vai para a próxima iteração do `for` quando conseguir ler um número.

Comment: Isso mesmo, deu certo aqui, bela explicação :)